# Reindex a group of products programmatically

Tags: magento-1, reindex

I'd like to know if it's possible to re-index not all product data, but just a group of them, based on their id. Something like this:

```
foreach($collection as $product){
     reindexSingleProduct($product->getID());
}
```

Comment: Which particular re-indexing you are trying to achieve here ?  Price, Stock, Attributes or any other ?

Comment: I'll try to re-index Stock for a start, but maybe I'll need to re-index all index types